# How to use grep command on multiple files at same time?

Tags: perl, grep

I wish to save some execution time on my code. So rather than applying grep on individual file (using foreach), I want to use grep on all files in an array at same time

I am using:

```
`grep -Pi "search string" $files`
```

but it's not giving me desired result because search string is in double quotes ("...") and complete command is in backticks.

Here `$files` contains path of all files separated by single space and `search string` has regex like `^\\s*abc|bcd|efg\\s+...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and install [`ack`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ack). You'll rarely use `grep` after that. `ack`:

- automatically recurses into subdirectories
- treats search parameter as a Perl regular expression
- rich set of command-line options more powerful and DWIMmy than `grep`

Install by installing the [`App::Ack`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::Ack) distribution from CPAN

Comment: thanks but search string has regex in it, does ack take care of regex too? i am newbee to perl
i have to search some thing like
"^\\s*abc|bcd|efg\\s+...

Comment: Yes, ack supports regular expressions.  It is written in pure Perl.  http://beyondgrep.com/

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
 $s1='search string';

 @x = qx(grep -Pi "$s1" $files);
```